# GCP Data Fusion to call stored procedure in Teradata?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion

We currently have some stored procedures on-premises in Teradata.

Due to some dependency issues, we don't plan on recreating these stored procedures as BQ routines. So these stored procedure will stay in Teradata (not BigQuery). Is there a way to call Teradata stored procedures from GCP Data Fusion?

FYI that we can't use Vertex AI's Python notebook to achieve this due to firewall rules. Thanks